# JPA automatic calling analyze table x compute statitics

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

We are working on some legacy code based on Open Jpa 2.2 interecting with Oracle. The code automatically issues statements like:

```
analyze table x compute statitics
```

We would like to avoid this as it happens when we do not want. It this possible? If yes how?

Comment: In order to do this you should remove those statements from your legacy code... There's no magic way of stopping a session from executing some things and not others. You should also replace them with [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII).

Comment: They are not in the code, they are issued automatically somewhere in the JPA components, based on my analysis. As said is this possible? If yes how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to highlight the solution to this problem I noticed in other pieces of sw:

The problem is in getIndexInfo() metatada class method. If the fourth parameter is set to false the system will calculate exact statistics: this should be avoided especially if in subsequent steps you recalculate these statistics (this is quite common in my experience as people wants to take control of these steps).

Answer (score 1):

<s>[DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68628) can prevent statistics gathering.</s>

```sql
--Create sample table.
create table x(a number);

--To gather stats: unlock stats, gather stats, then lock stats.
begin
    dbms_stats.unlock_table_stats(user, 'X');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'X');
    dbms_stats.lock_table_stats(user, 'X');
end;
/

--Any session that tries to gather stats without unlocking gets an exception.
analyze table x compute statistics;

ORA-38029: object statistics are locked
```

**UPDATE**

This is a JDBC bug: `Bug 4999817 : WHEN THE LAST FLAG TO GETINDEXINFO() IS TRUE, IT SHOULD NOT ANALYZE THE TABLE.`  It was fixed in 11g and there are patches for 10g.  You'll need an Oracle support account to read the full details of that bug, but you've already figured out most of it.

Comment: This will make the software crush as soon as the framework (based on my analysis) will try to gather statistics.

Comment: Is there a way to catch and ignore that exception?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid this?  Because the stats are bad, or because it's taking too long?  If it's only because the new stats are bad, then you can use a trigger that calls `DBMS_STATS.RESTORE_TABLE_STATS` to undo the changes.  If it's because the process is slow I think your only options are to fix the Java code or lock the stats and handle the exception.

Comment: The problem is related to performance. We want to take control of what happens moreover this step happens when indexes are not created: it is completely useless.

Comment: The problem is in getIndexInfo() metatada class method. If the fourth parameter is set to false the system will calculate exact statistics.